# Change class group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three buttons and each one has a CSS class. At click of one of them, i would like remove the class and add a new CSS class only for the clicked element. Furthermore, I need to keep pressed the selected button.
I searched some examples and I found that is possible do something like this:

```
$(".class").removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
```

This works for all buttons, but not only for one. I try to change this in

```
$(this).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
```

but this didn't work.

I make a fiddle for more compreansion: https://jsfiddle.net/90u6b3tj/3/

**EDIT**
I need the same behavior when i press a second time

Sorry for the basic problem.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/90u6b3tj/8/

Comment: Thanks for replay, but I need to keep pressed the selected button. anyway it dosn't works

Comment: All you need to do is change the line to $(this).toggleClass("active"); and switch the order of the two styles in your CSS sheet. Right now because "choice" comes after "active" it's always taking precedence regardless of whether the button is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle for a working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/90u6b3tj/10/

Here's the javascript part:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that the only reason this appears to work is that you have 'f' instead of the closing ; in one of the CSS styles. It DOES work, however, if you switch the order of the styles in the CSS as well.

Comment: Fixed the closing semicolon in the CSS styles.

Comment: Then have a meaningless internet point. Though I do find it amusing that there are seven answers for a problem that was solvable with a quick CSS change and editing one line of code. :P

Comment: Thanks for replay. It's ok, but what can i do if i want same the behavior when i press a second time for example?

Comment: What do you mean by same behaviour? This script does toggle the class `active` so that when you push the second time the button becomes again inactive.

Comment: I mean that when i press the first button, the class 'active' is added; when i press the second button, only the last button has the 'active' class. not the last two buttons.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you be more specific and describe what kind of behaviour you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to activate only one button at a time? Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/90u6b3tj/13/) jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

as you are adding your click events like so:-

```
<button id="hourly" class="choice" onclick="change()">Orario</button>
```

you could use `event.target`:-

```
function change(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.target).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
}
```

OR, change your event and pass in `this`:-

```
<button id="hourly" class="choice" onclick="change(this)">Orario</button>
```

so you can do:-

```
function change(element){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(element).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
}
```

OR better still:-

```
$('.choice').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
});
```

and remove the inline click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead.

```
$(".class").click(function(){
    $(".class").addClass("choice");
    $(".class").removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
});
```

Here, the "**choice**" class is removed only from the clicked class. Not from the others. Also the "**active**" class is added to the clicked one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `change(this)` in your `button` markup and refer to that element in your `change()` function, as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90u6b3tj/9/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //$(".choice").removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
  $(event.target).removeClass("choice").addClass("active");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="hourly" class="choice" onclick="change(event)">Orario</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="daily" class="choice" onclick="change(event)">Giornaliero</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="monthly" class="choice" onclick="change(event)">Mensile</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Should it possible so select more than one item as active?
If not, checkout this:

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <button id="hourly" class="choice">Orario</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="daily" class="choice">Giornaliero</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="monthly" class="choice">Mensile</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active { 
    background-color: #A60076;
    color: #FF0000;
}

.choice {
  background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    $("button").addClass('choice').removeClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('choice').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/90u6b3tj/11/) with the above code working.